# NUnit and NSubstitute fail to properly catch exception in unittest

Tags: c#, nunit, nsubstitute

I have a unittest using NUnit and NSubtitute with the code:

```
client.Read(Arg.Any<DATA>()).Throws(new Exception());

var response = service.Read()
```

service.Read() looks like this:

```
try
{
   var clientRead = client.Read();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw MessageException(ex);
}
```

When service.Read() is executed it will call the client.Read() and then go to the catch of service.Read(). However, at that point the unittest stops due to the system exception is thrown and my unittest stops running. How can I 'catch' this issue and continue my unittest?

Answer (score 1):

Catch the thrown exception and assert the expected behavior

For example, You can use `Assert.Throws<TException>`

```
//...

client.Read(Arg.Any<DATA>()).Throws(new Exception());

//Act
Action act = () => var response = service.Read();

//Assert
MessageException ex = Assert.Throws<MessageException>(act);
//...assert the exception for expected behavior
```